# Why does DIV AB converts from hex to decimal 8051

Tags: microcontroller, assembly, 8051

I was trying to solve a problem and I read that this code converts a number from hex to decimal 
I mean why . My idea is that div is just for division
can somebody answer my questions that I left as comments

`MOV   A,#0FFH      ;why do we need to do this
 MOV   P1,A         ;P1 as an INPUT
 MOV   A,P1         ;Get data from P1
 MOV   B,#10        ;to convert from hex to decimal
 DIV   AB           ;that the question why does div used to do this conversion
 MOV   R7,B         ;does this put 10 in the register r7
 MOV   B,#10
 DIV   AB
 MOV   R6,B         ;it does also puts 10 in the register r6?
 MOV   R5,A         ;if A <10     (why does this do )`

Comment: Could you please revert that edit?  I had the formatting fixed.  A picture is really not a good way to show your code.

Comment: It'd help to state *which* assy lang. this is, but **DIV AB** appears to be integer dividing A by B, then putting the remainder in B. Thus, for **FF** you'd have R7=5, R6=5, and R5=2.

Comment: @JRE check edit log...y'all were having an edit war.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB:  yeah, it was frustrating to fix the coding only for it to be mangled again.

Comment: Tried to but it gets worse - I had it formatted nicely like MCS-51 assembly an hour or so ago.

Comment: Here we are - back to how I had it before people started mucking about with it.

Answer (score 5):

Simple enough

A starts out being a number between zero and 255.

Lets say its FF i.e. 255..

Dividing by 10 gets you 25 in A and 5, the remainder, in B. That's the units value, so we save B to R7

Next we setup B with 10 again and divide the 25 by ten, and again store the remainder, this time in R6, as the tens digit.

What is left in A is the hundreds count, and we store that in R5.

So.. R5,6, and 7 now contain 2,5,5, the decimal equivalent of FF.

Here is a register trace if it helps..

[image]

Comment: Now I can agree with it & +1 ;)